# Do I need to make an agreement with Stack Exchange to create an app?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, mobile-app, windows-phone

There are Android and iOS Apps for Stack Exchange, but for Windows Phone I only see third-party wrappers, for example [this](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/software/content/Stack-Overflow_1.php) by Megasoft.

I just wonder if anybody can wrap any website and create an app, or if they have to make an agreement with Stack Exchange?

Comment: I made a somewhat extensive edit to the title of your question, please review it and edit if I've changed the meaning of your question at all.

Comment: edit is fine, more clear

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anyone can use the [public API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) exposed by Stack Exchange in order to create a new app, and there is even a [dedicated website](https://stackapps.com/) with a [special tag for such apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app).

As far as I can tell, no special agreement is required, you just need to [register your application](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register).

Also worth reading [How to list your application/library/wrapper/script here](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here), written by no other than Jeff Atwood, co-founder of Stack Overflow:

> If you've created an application, script, or library for use on the Stack Exchange network, that's fantastic!

Comment: but is it true only for Stack Exchange, or I can wrap any website, which I want?

Comment: No idea what you mean, sorry. My answer (and this whole site) is only for the scope of Stack Exchange. If you want to make an app for other sites (e.g. Facebook) you should really contact those other sites.

Comment: asked this question here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88446/wrapping-web-site

Answer (score 5):

For Stack Exchange wrapper apps: no, you don't need special permission. The [API](//api.stackexchange.com) is both extremely comprehensive and public - both very deliberately.

Hence, you're free to create an app that wraps the Stack Exchange sites without asking their permission or agreement first. However, be aware that normal trademark and copyright restrictions on Stack Exchange's assets apply, and you should also read the [API Terms of Use](//stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use) and the [trademark guidance](//stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (which is actually good information, not legalese).

I can't answer the same question for *any* website - the terms they apply to their services differ wildly. See their help centers, legal advice pages, or get in contact with a human to ask if it's OK.